# How to ignore a block in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-oci

I have a terraform code that is creating kubernetes cluster resource in Oracle cloud.
I want to ignore  `endpoint_config` block when the cluster is public and execute this block when the cluster is private. How can I achieve that

```
resource "oci_containerengine_cluster" "cluster" {
  count              = var.deploy_oke_cluster ? 1 : 0
  compartment_id     = var.compartment_id
  kubernetes_version = var.cluster_kubernetes_version
  name               = "oke-${var.environment}"
  vcn_id             = oci_core_virtual_network.base_vcn.id

  endpoint_config {
    is_public_ip_enabled = false
    subnet_id            = oci_core_subnet.snet-apiserver.id
  }
  options {
    add_ons {
      is_kubernetes_dashboard_enabled = true
      is_tiller_enabled               = false
    }

    kubernetes_network_config {
      pods_cidr     = var.pods_cidr
      services_cidr = var.services_cidr
    }
    service_lb_subnet_ids = [oci_core_subnet.snet-pub-lb.id]

  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with [dynamic blocks](https://www.terraform.io/docs/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks.html):

```
resource "oci_containerengine_cluster" "cluster" {
  count              = var.deploy_oke_cluster ? 1 : 0
  compartment_id     = var.compartment_id
  kubernetes_version = var.cluster_kubernetes_version
  name               = "oke-${var.environment}"
  vcn_id             = oci_core_virtual_network.base_vcn.id


  dynamic "endpoint_config" {

      for_each = var.is_public == true ? [1] : []    

      content {
        is_public_ip_enabled = false
        subnet_id            = oci_core_subnet.snet-apiserver.id
      }
  }


  options {
    add_ons {
      is_kubernetes_dashboard_enabled = true
      is_tiller_enabled               = false
    }

    kubernetes_network_config {
      pods_cidr     = var.pods_cidr
      services_cidr = var.services_cidr
    }
    service_lb_subnet_ids = [oci_core_subnet.snet-pub-lb.id]

  }
}
```

Comment: Marcin: can you help me with another question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69909662/how-to-fetch-id-of-a-variable-using-name-in-terraform