# How to fetch id of a variable using name in terraform?

Tags: terraform

I have a terraform resource in which I am trying to make a subnet_id variable dynamic. So I have varibles defined below in which `subnet_id  = "worker-subnet-1"`. I want to pass the name of the subnet and fetch the subnet id as I have multiple subnets. How can I do that.

```
resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "node_pool" {
  for_each       = var.nodepools
  cluster_id     = oci_containerengine_cluster.cluster[0].id
  compartment_id = var.compartment_id
  depends_on     = [oci_containerengine_cluster.cluster]

  kubernetes_version = var.cluster_kubernetes_version
  name               = each.value["name"]

  node_config_details {
    placement_configs {
      availability_domain = var.availability_domain
      subnet_id           = oci_core_subnet.each.value["subnet_name"].id
    }
    size = each.value["size"]
  }

  node_shape = each.value["node_shape"]

  node_shape_config {

    #Optional
    memory_in_gbs = each.value["memory"]
    ocpus         = each.value["ocpus"]
  }

  node_source_details {
    image_id    = each.value["image_id"]
    source_type = "IMAGE"

  }
  ssh_public_key = file(var.ssh_public_key_path)
}
```

These are my variables:

```
nodepools = {
  np1 = {
    name       = "np1"
    size       = 3
    ocpus      = 8
    memory     = 120
    image_id   = "test"
    node_shape = "VM.Standard2.8"
    subnet_name  = "worker-subnet-1"
  }
  np2 = {
    name       = "np2"
    size       = 2
    ocpus      = 8
    memory     = 120
    image_id   = "test"
    node_shape = "VM.Standard2.8"
    subnet_name  = "worker-subnet-1"
  }
}
```

any suggestions?

```
resource "oci_core_subnet" "snet-workers" {
  cidr_block                 = lookup(var.subnets["snet-workers"], "subnet_cidr")
  compartment_id             = var.compartment_id
  vcn_id                     = oci_core_virtual_network.base_vcn.id
  display_name               = lookup(var.subnets["snet-workers"], "display_name")
  dns_label                  = lookup(var.subnets["snet-workers"], "dns_label")
  prohibit_public_ip_on_vnic = true
  security_list_ids          = [oci_core_security_list.private_worker_nodes.id]
  route_table_id             = oci_core_route_table.rt-nat.id
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to use like below where change `<local resource name>` to the name you have given for your resource

```
subnet_id = oci_core_subnet.<local resource name>[each.value.subnet_id].id
```

Comment: What will the value of local resource name and how to declare it?

Comment: Also I want to read the value from variables and fetch the id.

Comment: I want to read the name from variables that's the whole point

Comment: getting error :  `An attribute name is required after a dot.` my declaration is `subnet_id           = oci_core_subnet.test-workers.[each.value.subnet_id].id`

Comment: I am getting a different error now ` Error: No value for required variable
│
│   on variables.tf line 49:
│   49: variable "nodepools" {
╵
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on ../avaprod.tfvars line 136:
│  136:     subnet_name = snet-worker1
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵
╷
│ Error: Variables not allowed
│
│   on ../avaprod.tfvars line 145:
│  145:     subnet_name = snet-worker2
│
│ Variables may not be used here.
╵`

Comment: For declaring resource ```oci_core_subnet``` you refer below link https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/oci/latest/docs/resources/core_subnet

you have declared it wrong - use below syntax.
```subnet_id = oci_core_subnet.test-workers[each.value.subnet_id].id```

Comment: I am getting adifferent error now

Comment: seems like your var.tf file doesnt have attribute ```"subnet_name"``` , check that . Else update the full code here.

Comment: it gives me errror: ```oci_core_subnet.snet-workers is object with 22 attributes```

Comment: I have added the subnet_name in my vars but now getting above error.

Comment: updated question. pls check

Comment: The original question has been addressed. For this to check you should put new question and provide full code with the input variables

Comment: posted new question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69911514/terraform-error-while-fetching-value-of-subnet-in-oci , can you help