# Terraform error while fetching value of subnet in oci

Tags: terraform

I have this code where I am trying to fetch the id of subnet via subnet name:

The code looks like this :

```
resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "node_pool" {
  for_each       = var.nodepools
  cluster_id     = oci_containerengine_cluster.cluster[0].id
  compartment_id = var.compartment_id
  depends_on     = [oci_containerengine_cluster.cluster]

  kubernetes_version = var.cluster_kubernetes_version
  name               = each.value["name"]

  node_config_details {
    placement_configs {
      availability_domain = var.availability_domain
      subnet_id           = oci_core_subnet.snet-workers[each.value.subnet_name].id
    }
    size = each.value["size"]
  }

  node_shape = each.value["node_shape"]

  node_shape_config {

    #Optional
    memory_in_gbs = each.value["memory"]
    ocpus         = each.value["ocpus"]
  }

  node_source_details {
    image_id    = each.value["image_id"]
    source_type = "IMAGE"

  }
  ssh_public_key = file(var.ssh_public_key_path)
}
```

My subnet code looks like:

```
resource "oci_core_subnet" "snet-workers" {
  cidr_block                 = lookup(var.subnets["snet-workers"], "subnet_cidr")
  compartment_id             = var.compartment_id
  vcn_id                     = oci_core_virtual_network.base_vcn.id
  display_name               = lookup(var.subnets["snet-workers"], "display_name")
  dns_label                  = lookup(var.subnets["snet-workers"], "dns_label")
  prohibit_public_ip_on_vnic = true
  security_list_ids          = [oci_core_security_list.private_worker_nodes.id]
  route_table_id             = oci_core_route_table.rt-nat.id
}
```

variables looks like:

```
variable "subnets" {
  description = "List of subnets to create for an environment"
  type = map(object({
    subnet_cidr  = string
    display_name = string
    dns_label    = string
  }))
}
```

my tfvars looks like

```
nodepools = {
  np1 = {
    name       = "np1"
    size       = 3
    ocpus      = 8
    memory     = 120
    image_id   = "test"
    node_shape = "VM.Standard2.8"
    subnet_name = "snet-worker1"
  }
  np2 = {
    name       = "np2"
    size       = 2
    ocpus      = 8
    memory     = 120
    image_id   = "test"
    node_shape = "VM.Standard2.8"
    subnet_name = "snet-worker2"
  }
}
```

But in terraform plan I am getting error as

```
 Error: Invalid index
│
│   on ../modules/oke/oke.tf line 39, in resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "node_pool":
│   39:       subnet_id           = oci_core_subnet.snet-workers[each.value.subnet_name].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.subnet_name is "snet-worker2"
│     │ oci_core_subnet.snet-workers is object with 22 attributes
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
╵
╷
│ Error: Invalid index
│
│   on ../modules/oke/oke.tf line 39, in resource "oci_containerengine_node_pool" "node_pool":
│   39:       subnet_id           = oci_core_subnet.snet-workers[each.value.subnet_name].id
│     ├────────────────
│     │ each.value.subnet_name is "snet-worker1"
│     │ oci_core_subnet.snet-workers is object with 22 attributes
│
│ The given key does not identify an element in this collection value.
```

Can someone help

Comment: What is the definition of `oci_core_subnet.snet-workers`?

Comment: @Marcin: added the correct code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following:

```
subnet_id           =  oci_core_subnet.snet-workers[each.value.subnet_name].id
```

would only work if you had used `for_each` while creating `oci_core_subnet.snet-workers`. Since you are not using `for_each`, it should be:

```
subnet_id           =  oci_core_subnet.snet-workers.id
```

**UPDATE**

To keep using original version:

```
resource "oci_core_subnet" "snet-workers" {

  for_each                   = var.subnets

  cidr_block                 = each.value["subnet_cidr"]
  compartment_id             = var.compartment_id
  vcn_id                     = oci_core_virtual_network.base_vcn.id
  display_name               = leach.value[""display_name"]
  dns_label                  = each.value["dns_label"]
  prohibit_public_ip_on_vnic = true
  security_list_ids          = [oci_core_security_list.private_worker_nodes.id]
  route_table_id             = oci_core_route_table.rt-nat.id
}
```

Comment: I know this syntax. But I am using tfvars which has subnet name and I am trying to fetch id from name. so hence how can I update the  `oci_core_subnet.snet-workers`. Updated code with tfvars value

Comment: Since Because oci_core_subnet.snet-workers has "for_each" set, its attributes must be accessed on specific instances. How can it will be accesssed by other resources now `destination = oci_core_subnet.snet-workers.cidr_block` how to modify this

Comment: @cloudbud Once you add `for_each` to one resource, you have to re-factor your entire codebase that uses that resource. Depending on the size of the codebase, you can have hundrets of such errors to fix. You do it same way as with `subnet_id`.

Comment: something like this ?oci_core_subnet.snet-workers[each.key]

Comment: @cloudbud Yes, but it depends on your code. Your code in question does not use `destination` at all, thus you can make new question about this, as this is new problem.

Comment: okay marcin. I will do

Answer (score 1):

You have to define a "oci_core_subnet" for each entry in "subnets" variable. Something like this:

```
resource "oci_core_subnet" "snet-workers" {
  for_each   = var.subnets
  cidr_block = each.value.subnet_cidr
  ...
}
```